# How to reconstruct array to make most recent time is on top, and passed time is shifted to last part

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

Let's say I receive an array which always been ordered according to it's timestamp like below:

```
// assuming the number means TIMESTAMP, and 0 means NOW.
[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2];
```

And I want to reconstruct it into below

```
[0, 1, 2, -2, -1];
```

Is there anyway in JavaScript can achieve this?

My current solution:

```
const games = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2];
const now = Moment();
const passedGames = [];
const upcomingGames = [];
for (let i = 0, l = games.length; i < l; i++) {
  const game = games[i];
  const hasBegun = Moment(game).isBefore(now);
  hasBegun ? passedGames.push(game) : upcomingGames.push(game);
}

return [...upcomingGames, ...passedGames];
```

---

Reason why I am asking this question.
I receive a array of NBA games, each of them has start time,
in front end, I need to always show the most upcoming game,
that means array should always starts from zero.
If there is any game already began, I need to shift it to last,
that's why I am expecting the outcome would look like this.

```
[0, 1, 2, -2, -1];
```

Comment: You need to explain what "certain" is in the second array.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What is the reason for that sorting? AFAIK you go zero, positive in order, negative in reverse order. Is that correct?

Comment: When it was numeric it was straightforward...Now you changed it to invalid strings that have to be fixed to even test with and is far less straightforward to sort

Comment: I take it you are dealing with actual timestamps, not those exact phrases

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes you are right, I put phrases just want to make it more descriptive, but actually I am dealing with timestamp.

Comment: Using timestamps would ironically make your problem a lot easier to understand. For example, what is the corting logic in your desired output?

Comment: `[...upcomingMeetings.sort((a,b) => a - b), ...passedMeetings.sort((a,b) => a - b)]`

Comment: your "current solution" ... declares `passedItems` and  `upcomingItems` - but uses `passedMeetings` and `upcomingMeetings` ... declares `item` then pushes `meeting` - so ... doesn't look like your code would even run without errors in the console

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, thanks for reminding, already updated it.

Answer (score 2):

First, `filter` out the `now`, the `later`, and the `before` - then `sort` and concatenate them together:

```js
const array = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
now = array.filter(e => e == 0),
later = array.filter(e => e > 0),
before = array.filter(e => e < 0);

const result = [...now, ...later.sort((a, b) => a - b), ...before.sort((a, b) => a - b)];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.splice();` is what you need to achieve this. Here's an example. It seems like you lack some understanding with arrays though, I recommend you try to really understand the answers given forth instead of copy and pasting them, so I made the array continue from 10 after 9. Do some experimentation and you might learn a thing or two about loops or arrays who knows.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let inc = 10;

for(let i=0; i < array.length; i++){
  array.splice(i, 1, inc++);
};

console.log(array);
```